# cmake - show other class files in project

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I recently started with cmake in my project and managed to include SDL using CMAKE.

Now I added a simple class file, which is included in my `main.cpp`

After configuring/generating the project again my Source Files looks like that :

[image]

My setup

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3.2)
project (2dgameengine)

set(MAIN_FILE
    src/main.cpp
)

add_executable(2dgameengine
    ${MAIN_FILE}
)

target_sources(2dgameengine PUBLIC ${EXTRA_FILE})


set (SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR libs/sdl2/include)
set (SDL2_SOURCE_DIR libs/sdl2/src)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(2dgameengine ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>


#include "Tile.cpp"

int main () {

 return 0;
}
```

Tile.cpp

```
class Tile {
   // ...
}
```

**How can I make Tile.cpp visible in my xcode project?**

***EDIT***
This is nothing which will hit a real world at any time. I was just to lazy to split my *.cpp class in an *.h and *.cpp file. So I just included the *.cpp file - even if it not the correct way - this is only for testing purposes

I tried to set it as another source file in cmake, which does not work because it is included in my "main.cpp" which gives a linker error

Comment: Normally included file has a `.h` extension (*header* file), not a `.cpp` (*source* file). What do you mean by `make Tile.cpp visible in my xcode project`? For make the program compileable, you need to specify include directory, which contains the file included.

Comment: What is your reason for including a `.cpp` file in another `.cpp` file? It's extremely non-standard.

Comment: This is a problem inside cmake because cmake treats differently header files and source file, and it infers if a file is header or source using its extension.

Comment: @Oliv - thank you . this helped a lot. I tried to split it also in hpp and cpp which works also fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the file in the target's sources normally:

```
add_executable(2dgameengine
    ${MAIN_FILE}
    src/Tile.cpp
)
```

and tell CMake to treat it as a header file:

```
set_property(SOURCE src/Tile.cpp PROPERTY HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
```

This will prevent CMake from generating compilation rules for it.

Comment: thanks.
Is it also possible to show  *.h files in project structure? If I want to edit them I always have to re-include them in my project after running cmake

Comment: @xhallix Of course it is. Just list them in the target. You don't even have to set them as header-only, CMake recognises that based on the extension. In fact, showing up in IDEs is precisely why listing all of a target's constituent files, not just compiled ones, is encouraged CMake practice.

Comment: @xhallix Side note: why the `MAIN_FILE` variable? You can just list the file directly.

Comment: yep you are right - it is a "do anything to get it to work " - relict ;)

Comment: could you give me a short hint on what you mean with "Just list them in the target"? quiet new to cmake - are you refering to `target_sources` ?

Comment: @xhallix No, to `add_executable`. `target_sources` is only useful if you need to add sources to a target *after* it's defined, possibly based on a condition, in a different file, etc. Just like the answer has `src/Tile.cpp` in there, add `src/Tile.hpp` on a new line.